# Can You Use <textarea> Outside the Scope of a <form>

Tags: textarea

I want to use the features and functionality that the `<textarea>` tag offers in browsers. I want to use it merely to hold a large block of information that can be viewed through the use of the scrollbars that come with the `<textarea>` tag.

So my question is can I use it without using `<form></form>` tags?

I want to be sure that I use it properly for contemporary and future browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just try using it and see if it works?

Comment: Oh, it works okay @nathanhayfield. I am just wondering if it is a proper and compliant use of the tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the standards the `textarea` element should be a descendant of a `form` element.
HTML5 allows to place `textarea` outside the form but have a `form` attribute filled.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea

But as I know you'll not get any errors in major browsers using `textarea` outside the form and without the `form` attribute.

For the purpose you've described in your question, you can just use a `div` element with vertical scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Ybznv/

```
#log {
    height: 256px;
    width: 512px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EvgeniyNaydenov for explaining and offering an alternative solution! I will end up using your solution.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can, but if its just scrolling use a div instead and style it like this in css:

example:

```
div {
overflow-x:scroll;
height:200px;
width:200px;
border:solid black 1px;
}
```

demo:
http://jsbin.com/ugusos/2/edit

Comment: Ah, that is very cool. I think that is actually the direction I should be going. Thanks @user1721135

Comment: Thanks @user1721135. I am going to use your solution (along with _at_ EvgeniyNaydenov's answer). I accepted _at_ EvgeniyNaydenov's answer because he actually addressed the scope of my question. Others that come here to view this question will want to focus on the associated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use textarea tags outside of a form and they will display and allow text to be inserted and edited, but not being tied to a form their uses will likely be limited.  Although I suppose you could always use document.getElementById("") for the text area...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate being able to vote up on all the answers I find on this site now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use outside of a form,

But you could also use a div element and then use the contenteditable Attribute so that a user can edit the information.

http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Comment: Ok, thanks @StuartGrant. But I simply want to use the tag for displaying content and not for the purpose to let the user conceivably change the info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use textarea outside of form; there is no problem in it.

PS: But there is no good reason to use textarea out or form. You can use div instead.