# wxPython htmlWindow <textarea> not working correctly

Tags: python, html, window, wxpython

I am writing a simple program using `wx.html.htmlWindow`, and I have a problem: when I try to render `<textarea></textarea>`, it is not being shown! Am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
import wx
import wx.html

class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        if "gtk2" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            self.html.SetStandardFonts()
        self.html.SetPage("""<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Header</h1>

<textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>""")
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
HTML = MyHtmlFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

**N.B.:**
When I tried `<textarea>` with `wx.html2.WebView`, it worked with no problems.

Comment: WxPython's htmlWindow is old, clunky and has many problems. You're better off using WebView.

Comment: @mid_kid, is there wxPython 2.9 for linux fedora? Because I couldn't find it :(

Comment: A quick search tells me you have to compile it yourself. Which is not a difficult task (as there are copy-paste tutorials), but I don't like recommending people to do so. Because if done wrong, it can screw up your system. Next to the fact that once installed from source, it's very difficult to remove (This is what packages are for). Sorry, but you're on your own here, my friend.

Comment: Ok, thx :) Will try it anyway

Comment: @mid_kid, I had built wxPython 2.9, but ran into problem when using wx.html2: `NotImplementedError: wx.html2 is not available on this platform.`. Googling doesn't help alot as I don't know English very well, and can not understand everything

Comment: I've never tried wx.html2 on linux. It may be the case that it's not available on linux. Or the build may have failed somewhere. Or the build has a switch to enable wx.html2 support. Or something completely different is going on. Either way, I can't find any useful information to help you with this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea>` elements should either reside in a `<form>` element or expose a `form` attribute (in HTML5). See [Can You Use `<textarea>` Outside the Scope of a `<form>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14528951/464709).

Since your `<textarea>` element does not reside in a `<form>`, I strongly suspect the HTML renderer ignores it.

Try:

```
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>

<form>
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried this and still no result. Nothing appears ( except for `Header` )...

Comment: @Vik2015, looks like my suspicion was wrong then. I'll leave this answer around for now so other users who may have the same idea as me can see this is not the source of your problem.