# Text inside <a> tag not being displayed?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to display text under my image but it wont work. My image displays but not my text.

The `textarea` appears but it has no text and I cannot click and write on it. Although if I `Ctrl+F` it says the words are there but I cant see them nor are they highlighted

```
<div id = "folderlist">
    <a href="">
        <image  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file:  'folderimg.png')}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
        <textarea class="captionText"placeholder="your default   text">please display some text</textarea>
    </a>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#folderlist {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 1500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21%;
    right: 8.1%;
    text-align: center;
}

#folderlist a {
    margin: 15px;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: .8;    
    color:black;
}

#folderlist a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    border-color: red;
}

.captionText {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    text-color:black;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

I have tried different variations by removing `placeholder` using an input area and even just using `<p>` tags.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried also the following:

```
<a style='text-decoration: none; color: orange;'>
    <img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file:  'folderimg.png')}" width="100px" height="100px">
    <div style='width: 130px; text-align: center;'>I just love to visit this most beautiful place in all the world.</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you have a stranded `<a/>` tag and a `<textarea>` inside another `<a>` tag. Fix up your HTML first and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: @Steve That was my copy and paste mistake my bad that's not the problem

Comment: @Steve can you have a <textarea> inside a <a>? How else would I display text under the picture?

Comment: Better option here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528951/can-you-use-textarea-outside-the-scope-of-a-form for displaying text similarly to a textarea, but not with a form.

Comment: @hat_to_the_back with a `<p>` or `<span>` tag. `<textarea>` in this case, even if it was valid, is semantically incorrect for it's usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct also says that anything intractable cannot be inside of a link. Would a textarea be considered intractable?

Comment: @Steve Can you please see above edit. I dont know why it has been voted down? Its a valid question

Comment: @hat_to_the_back the downvote probably come from someone seeing your original question. I've edited it to be a bit more readable. Your edit also helps as that is more valid HTML.

Comment: @Steve thanks for that, any idea as to why it wont display.

Comment: @Steve You should try the couple of suggestions you have been given so far. Don't use a text area. Try something else.

Comment: @Jeff.Clark wrong person!

Comment: Hahaha, so it is. Must have been one of those things where I was looking at your name while typing and just transposed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
#folderlist {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 1500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21%;
    right: 8.1%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Setting the `font-size` to **0** tends to make text invisible :)

Comment: Great spot, it was late :P

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. Just do one thing.
Put # in the anchor tag.

```
<a href="#">
    <image  src="cool.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    <textarea class="captionText"placeholder="your default   text">please display some text</textarea>
</a>
```

**else there is no problem in code**

Answer (score -1):

A textarea  is a form input. It's not something you use for just displaying text. Use a 'p' tag instead

Comment: I don't know why this is massively downvoted.  It's the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Joshua Comeau is correct - the markup doesn't make sense.

`<a>` is an anchor tag.  It is only allowed to contain certain things.  Form elements, such as `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` are not among them.

Textareas are the large text editing areas that you expect in a mail system.  You don't use them to display text.

You can just put that text there not wrapped in anything at all.  That's probably what you want.

If you just need something to attach style rules to, use a `<span>`.

If what you're trying to do is to get a rectangular area to put text into, you want a `<div>` instead.

`<textarea>` within `<a>` is not legal, and will never work in a compliant browser.

The code in your "I have also tried" is actually perfectly valid, and what you want to do.